# No attachments when reading messages (cannot save attachments)

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I'm accessing an MS O365 Mail account using python and O365 libraries and can not access/save the file attachments for messages

I've done this using normal IMAP etc but now, because we have to user oauth2 and all that - I have to access the mailbox either through MS-Graph or some other way.

I went for the python-O365 libraries that allow me to do what I need.

I can get the folders and messages (names, bodies etc) but when I try to use the message.attachments method - I get the message that the number of attachments is unknown.

I know that there are two XLSX attachments for this message as I sent it myself and also I can verify that I'm reading the correct message because I can read the body of it.

I've searched for examples of saving attachments (using the O365 libs) but they don't address the problem (they iterate over the attachments collection - but I don't have any attachments).

I have read that attachments are stored separately from messages and that these need to be fetched separately but somehow this seems wrong?

The below code illustrates the problem...

```py
for message in inbox.get_messages(5):
    print(message.subject)
    if message.subject == 'test':
        print('here')
        for att in message.attachments:
            print('also here')
            print(att.attachment_name)
            print(att.attachment_type)
            att.save()
```

From the above I get the text 'here' printed  - so I know the correct message is being used. I don't get the text 'also here' which I should get as there are two files in the message.

So - any ideas how I can get my attachments saved?

Comment: As an update on this...

There was a problem accessing shared folders - this is now resolved by turning on the permissions in Azure.

This did not resolve the problem with attachments but does confirm that something isn't correct.

Comment: Hi @chris mellor can u share the oauth2 graph api connectivity,can u share the code.it would be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just shows what a little time, an early morning and some good coffee can bring...

I found the answer. it was buried in the issues tracker for the O365 lib on github.

The following code works as it should:

```
for message in inbox.get_messages(limit=10, download_attachments=True):
    if message.subject == 'test with file':
        print('here')
        if message.has_attachments:
            print('also here')
            print(message.attachments)
            for att in message.attachments:
                print(att)
                att.save()
```

Compare that to the original code and you will see that I need to instruct get_messages to download_attachments=True and also the mechanism for accessing the attachments has changed.

Anyways - it's now working:)

Comment: There is a little update to this story...

it appears that Outlook can use illegal characters in filenames. O365 API will not save these files and return False if you use the att.save() method.

What I did (and maybe not best way - but works - is to strip out illegal characters and then do this:

att.save(location=mailDir, custom_name=fixFileName(att.name))

The documentation doesn't mention the two variables that you can pass in but if you look through the source code - you can see them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11307248/chris-mellor Thanks this is very helpful . I made this mistake of not setting download_attachments = True and were finding 0 attachments to my bad.

Comment: @ChrisMellor This saved me hours I think! Thanks

Comment: @ChrisMellor for posting the question and your own solution, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar. This was driving me mad

Comment: @ChrisMellor Great Job! One more thing I wanted to add it would be much better if we can get name and other information about the attachment in question before actually downloading it to save bandwidth and more importantly time during mission critical applications. :thumbsup:

Comment: https://github.com/O365/python-o365/issues/334 That's original source of the code and shows how to get the attachment name as well.

Comment: It has been 2 days struggling on chatgpt solutions, stackoverflow days would never end I think. I thank god that I stumbled upon your solution. You sir are amazing.